# how to visit a springmvc project which run in dubbo Main

Tags: java, spring-mvc, port

I create a spring project,updated the springmvc dependency 
this is my pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
        <artifactId>dubbo</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>*</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.curator</groupId>
        <artifactId>curator-framework</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

As you see,I added springmvc and update log4j version.
and my Main method is like this:

```
public class Starter {

public static void main(String[]  args){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("dubbo.spring.config", "classpath:applicationContext.xml");
    ConfigUtils.addProperties(properties);
    Main.main(args);
}
```

}

I run it,there is no error

but i can visit the project with port 80 or 8080

how to fix it? thanks

Comment: question not clear, you can't or you can visit the project with port 80 or 8080

Comment: sorry for my terrible Enginsh

Comment: I mean,when the project starting, i can see my controller mapped

Comment: > Mapped "{[/sayHello],methods=[POST]}"

but when i key http://localhost:8080/sayHello in my Chrome Restlet Client, I get 404 Response

Comment: and also localhost:80/sayHello too

Comment: I pushed my code in git https://github.com/kanghouchao/dubboprovider.git  and consumer: https://github.com/kanghouchao/dubboconsumer.git

Answer (score 0):

Main.main is a method in Dubbo container, according to the loader configuration, it should load `SpringContainer` which will load a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` and start it.

So this question depends on what you have in your `applicationContext.xml` file, if you don't want to expose controller you can modify `applicationContext.xml` to remove controller or package-scan.